# Java EE integration test with Spock

Tags: jboss, integration-testing, spock

I have `JBoss` + `Java EE` application. I would like to run integration test against it using Spock.

So I claim it's possible to run tests after context started:

```
public class ExampleContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        // run Spock
    } 
}
```

Please, correct me if I am wrong. Point me to example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too broad and cannot be covered here. You have a lot of reading ahead

First take a look at Arquillian

http://arquillian.org/

Then at the Spock extension

https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-testrunner-spock